# Join Query Sort by Related Table in Eloquent Not Quite Working

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a few tables in my database:

- Questions <-(Many to Many)-> Surveys
- Questions (Has Many)-> Answers
- Questions (Has Many)-> Orders *for sorting
- Survey (Has Many)-> Orders *for sorting questions within a survey

My goal is to load all the questions within a given survey and sort them in a specific order.  However, I cannot seem to make this work.  I've tried many different variations of the query below, and it always "almost" works, but a few questions will be out of order.  I'm not great with SQL so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

```
$questions = Survey::find($survey->id)->questions()
                    ->join('orders as o', 'o.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
                    ->orderBy('o.order',  'desc')
                    ->groupBy('questions.id')
                    ->get();
```

I'm then adding them to an array and calling them in the view with:

```
($survey_questions[$survey->id] as $q)
```

**UPDATE**

Well... I don't think this is probably the best solution, (so I'm not marking it as an answer) but at least it works. To get things to order correctly, I had to initially select surveys and build joins from there, then create a separate array of `question_id => answers` to cycle through in my view... it works, but I'm quite sure it isn't ideal.

```
$survey_responses = array();
        $survey_questions = array();
        $question_answers = array();
        foreach($surveys as $survey) {
            $responses = $survey->responses()->where('survey_id', '=', $survey->id)->count();
            $survey_responses[$survey->id] = $responses;

            $questions = Order::where('survey_id', '=', $survey->id)                    
                        ->join('questions as q', 'q.id', '=', 'orders.question_id')
                        ->select('q.*') // add anything you need here
                        ->orderByRaw('orders.order asc')
                        ->groupBy('q.id')
                        ->get();

            $survey_questions[$survey->id] = $questions; 

            //make question_id => answers array because I can't figure out the damn select query
            foreach($survey->questions as $question) {
                foreach($question->answers as $answer) {
                    $question_answers[$question->id][$answer->id] = $answer->answer;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with eloquent you need to specify the columns you want to `select` if using `joins`. Otherwise `ids` (and possibly other columns) will be overriden by the related table's values, and the result is wrong.

```
$questions = Survey::find($survey->id)->questions()
     ->join('orders as o', 'o.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
     ->orderBy('o.order',  'desc')
     ->groupBy('questions.id')
     ->select('questions.*') // add anything you need here
     ->get();
```

Comment: Hmm... I'd tried adding `select()` before, I just did it again for good measure.  Still, all the correct information is being pulled up, not actually ordered by o.order.

Comment: Show the relevant tables then